# Servo motor initial position hack

Tags: arduino, motor, dc-motor, motor-controller, servo

I'm working with MG966R servo motors and would like to physically change its initial position. I would like that as soon as it's turned on and the Arduino puts the servo in its initial position (0 degrees) the actual servo is at 90 degrees.

Example: When the Arduino gives instruction to turn an angle of 90 degrees, the servo motor turns 90 degrees but the position is at 180 degrees due to its physical initial position being already turned at 90 degrees.

Note: The servo motors have a fixed slot in structure and the horns are rotating another link, thus, the modification must be in the internal servo.

Software/coding can't be changed either.

A picture is attached for visual reference.

[image]

Comment: Couldn't you just put the horn on in a different position?

Comment: @BruceAbbott Unfortunately, no. the modification must be internally.

Comment: modify the servo internally

Comment: @jsotola That's what I would like to do but I'm not sure what I have to adjust once I open up the servo. I saw few posts on how to adjust some gears but I'm not sure which and how I need to rotate them.  Maybe, you have a link to guide me to do so?

Comment: You’ll need to change the physical relationship between the output horn and the potentiometer.  From memory they are both on the same shaft (which is logical).  You may or may not be able to change this.  Is the output horn not mounted on a spline?

Comment: https://yaoota.com/en-eg/product/mg966r-servo-motor-15-kgcm-holding-torque-for-arduino-projec-price-from-souq-egypt                    https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fcomponents101.com%2Fsites%2Fdefault%2Ffiles%2Fcomponents%2FMG996R-Servo-Motor.jpg&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fcomponents101.com%2Fmotors%2Fmg996r-servo-motor-datasheet&tbnid=dRBdLN0T7bAZnM&vet=12ahUKEwjOkZjy58_5AhWm8LsIHeENDh8QMygHegUIARDdAQ..i&docid=HgIRMWs_KG5NYM&w=500&h=382&q=mg966r&ved=2ahUKEwjOkZjy58_5AhWm8LsIHeENDh8QMygHegUIARDdAQ

Comment: @Frog the above links are the type of servo in question.

Comment: Why don’t you just spend a little time looking and understanding how it works. It is a simple mechanism.  Frog has given you the hint. Depending on the actual design of your servo, it might be easy or  physically difficult. Maybe buy another identical one to play with.

Comment: The first line of my previous comment is intended to be an encouragement and not sarcasm. When I re-read it, I realised it my be interpreted negatively. Unfortunately I can’t edit it.

Comment: _"Unfortunately, no. the modification must be internally"_ - this is very hard to believe. Even if a custom coupler is used it still has to fit the spline, with many possible positions. The robotic arm ("https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:1838120") in your photo apparently uses standard servo horns bolted onto the mechanism, which could be orientated whichever way you like. Why can't you do this?